# Running bounding-box queries with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, extents, mongodb

I am working on a google map application, to display the items that are listed in the selected rectangular area. Below image give you some understanding.

Based on the co-ordinates (topLeft,bottomRight), i am running bounding box query to find the items in  mongo db. But it always returns the this error when running the box queries

```
 Error: $box needs 2 fields (bottomLeft,topRight)
```

I know that i have passed topLeft,bottomRight points instead the mongo expected one (bottomLeft,topRight).

How do I calculate the bottomLeft,topRight values based on the co-ordinates from Google Maps?

This is the actual value i got trouble with

```
bound_box = [[80.22050443383796, 13.051049734963444], [80.2393871853028, 13.043106313697518]]]
```

and ruby code for finding bounding box values in mongo db

```
items = Item.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$box" => [bound_box]}},
                              :category => BSON::ObjectId(cat), :sub_category => BSON::ObjectId(sub)).order_by(:created_at => :desc).skip(@current_page * 5).limit(5).paginate
```

this is the line giving problem

```
items = Item.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$box" => [bound_box]}})
```

which is similar to the mongodb query

```
 db.items.find({"loc" : {"$within" : {"$box" : bound_box}}})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your coordinates are *y,x* formatted, and you have :

- topLeft : 42,10
- bottomRight : 31,21

then, to calculate bottomLeft, you get the *y* from bottomRight and get the *x* from topLeft

and to calculate topRight, , you get the *y* from topLeft and get the *x* from bottomRight  :

- bottomLeft : 31,10
- topRight : 42,21

**In case it is not clear enough, just take a pen and a piece of paper and draw it!**

Comment: yeah, thats what i did first after the problem, but the problem still persists with the new values too. so i got totally confused and asked whether there is any other way to do it.. :(

Comment: could it be a cache problem? or the problem is somewhere. Is your code online?

Comment: i have updated th question with more info, check out

Comment: Just an idea. Are you sure mongodb is not expecting latitude first, then longitude. Like that : *bound_box = [[13.051049734963444, 80.22050443383796], [13.043106313697518, 80.2393871853028]]]*

Comment: mongo expects longtitude first.. so it wont work.. Finally after hours of digging i found its a problem in ruby driver not in the new calculated bottomLeft, and topRight values.. it works fine now...